# Old manga about a boy who's released after being trapped in darkness with a dragon/demon that survives in shadow

Tags: story-identification, manga

Looking for an old manga about a boy who has been trapped in darkness with a dragon/demon that survives in shadow. The boy gets released to help defeat the shadow/darkness demon. Both the boy and dragon become friends and the boy is naïve about the world around him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: would be useful to clarify "old" a bit - for example, when did you first read it? Maybe you could approximate the year of its publication?

Comment: Was this definitely "shadow", or could the boy have been sacrificed to a flame dimension, that was supposed to kill him but he ends up absorbing the flame instead and emerging years later?